# OpenLayers + Google adsense

Tags: google-maps, openlayers, adsense

How can I use Google Adsense inside OpenLayers using a google maps layer?

Code to use adsense inside a google maps (v2) map:

```
map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("Gmap"));
adsManager = new GAdsManager(
    map, 
    "ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
    {
        maxAdsOnMap : 4,
        style: 'adunit'
    }
);
adsManager.enable();

## The HTML:
<div id="Gmap"></div>
```

[image: result ads in google maps v2]

Code to display google maps in openlayers:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map("olmap")
var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Streets", {numZoomLevels: 20});
map.addLayers([gmap]);

## The HTML:
<div id="olmap"></div>
```

Is there any way to get the google maps object inside openlayers? Then I could use the first code to add the ads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! Looking at Openlayers source code and firebug :)

It seems that when you have this code

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map("olmap")
var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Streets", {numZoomLevels: 20});
map.addLayers([osm, gmap]);

## The HTML:
<div id="olmap"></div>
```

you can use this js to reference the google maps object

```
map.baseLayer.mapObject
```

So, according to [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advertising), it would be something like

```
## html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=adsense&sensor=true_or_false"></script>
<div id="olmap"></div>

## js
map = new OpenLayers.Map("olmap")
var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Streets", {numZoomLevels: 20});
map.addLayers([gmap]);

var adUnitDiv = document.createElement('div');
var adUnitOptions = {
  format: google.maps.adsense.AdFormat.HALF_BANNER,
  position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP,
  map: map.baseLayer.mapObject,
  visible: true,
  publisherId: 'YOUR_PUBLISHER_ID'
}
adUnit = new google.maps.adsense.AdUnit(adUnitDiv, adUnitOptions);
```

(not tested)

Comment: Note that the Google Maps adsense library has now been deprecated: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/advertising